# How to use the function given in the link + javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to javascript functioning and wanted to see its functioning regarding pasting dynamic data in the html.

I have this link where they tell what to use for the same in a table but I can't figure out how to do the same...

The link to the code is [javascript link](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2j9qG/)

I first made an html page using the html shown and then added the lines of javascript shown below it in `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">` tag.

But I am not getting the same output.... What am i doing wrong ?

Please help...

Comment: Sorry to hijack this question, but did jsFiddle change their font for the code or is it just me?

Comment: Somehow it is not at all clear what you want. You want to do same as shown in the example? How can we tell you what you are doing wrong if we don't know your code?

Comment: @Felix Kling I want to emulate the same thing on my computer and for the same I wrote it just like that copy and paste within the javascript tags.... So it looks that I need jquery too for it (?) And i wanted to know was that what else would be the change in code for it....

Comment: @user671805: Yep. You need jQuery (as you can see it is selected at the right side) and put everything in the `load` or `ready` event handler. Just have a look at the source of the result. But before you do anything you really should read a [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) and [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) tutorial.

Comment: @Felix Okayzz and also just as a side question we can add anything that we want dynamically right... For example here if we want to add links stored as string in array it would be possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the example you're trying to imitate is doing client-side data binding.  First of all, yes, you need to reference jQuery script in your page.  Secondly, you'd be better off accomplishing client-side data binding with the [jQuery Templates plugin](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).